# jpg conversion to shapefile

Tags: georeferencing, jpg

Please, I have a jpg image which I want to work on, but I have a problem with it. I understand that I need a shapefile that is already georeferenced to georeferenced the jpg. Pls, how do I know that a map is georeferenced? And also, how doing I bring the two jpg to appear on the base mapa at thesame time in arcmap?

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking/what you are attempting to do.  What software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

A map is not georeferenced. Shapefiles and feature classes (s/fc, for short)) can and usually do have a coordinate system, either geographic or projected. Other items, typically imagery such as a jpg or CAD data, are then georeferenced to the s/fc.

Basically, georeferencing refers to the process of 'rubbersheeting' the image to known reference points in the s/fc by tying points in the image to corresponding points in the s/fc until the image lines up with the s/fc.

In Arc, you can zoom to the area that should be georeferenced. Using the Georeferencing toolbar, select the jpg you want in the dropdown list box. Click the down arrow next to the 'Georeferencing' menu and click 'Fit To Display. This will put your image in the area on screen. [See help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t000000mn000000) for more details.